Cite a specific section of my own paper
I am using APA 7th. I want to cite a specific section of my own paper.
How to say look into section X for more details.
Please show both parenthetical and narrative.

Can you explain why you don't just cite the paper? Why would you need to point to a specific section?

"Look into section X for more details."

Are you asking about cross referencing from within the same paper, or a precise citation from another document? The former doesn't require a formal citation, and in the latter case the fact that it's your own paper doesn't matter.

@Anyon I am asking about cross referencing from within the same paper.
